# JMS Message Selector in Mule using date

Tags: mule, delay

In Mule 3.3.1, during async processing, when any of my external services are down, I would like to place the message on a queue (`retryQueue`) with a particular "next retry" timestamp. The flow that processes messages from this `retryQueue` selects messages based on "next retry" time as in if "next retry" time is past current time, select the message for processing. Similar to what has been mentioned in following link.

[Retry JMS queue implementation to deliver failed messages after certain interval of time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17838222/retry-jms-queue-implementation-to-deliver-failed-messages-after-certain-interval)

Could you please provide sample code to achieve this?

I tried:

```
<on-redelivery-attempts-exceeded>
  <message-properties-transformer scope="outbound">
<add-message-property key="putOnQueueTime" value="#[function:datestamp:yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ssZ]" />
  </message-properties-transformer>
  <jms:outbound-endpoint ref="retryQueue"/>
</on-redelivery-attempts-exceeded>
```

and on the receiving flow

```
<jms:inbound-endpoint ref="retryQueue">
<!-- I have no idea how to do the selector.... 
 I tried....<jms:selector expression="#[header:INBOUND:putOnQueueTime > ((function:now) - 30)]"/>, but obviously it doesn't work. Gives me an invalid message selector. -->
</jms:inbound-endpoint>.
```

Another note: If I set the outbound property using

```
<add-message-property key="putOnQueueTime" value="#[function:now]"/>,
```

it doesn't get carried over as part of header. That's why I changed it to:

```
<add-message-property key="putOnQueueTime" value="#[function:datestamp:yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ssZ]" />
```

Comment: What have you tried? Share your configuration and problems so we can help you.

Comment: @DavidDossot Do you need any additional information?

Answer (score 1):

The expression in:

```
<jms:selector expression="#[header:INBOUND:putOnQueueTime > ((function:now) - 30)]"/>
```

should evaluate to a valid JMS selector, which is not the case here. Try with:

```
<jms:selector expression="putOnQueueTime > #[XXX]"/>
```

replacing XXX with an expression that creates the time you want.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is the place where I'm stuck! I need to figure out the #[XXX] which will give me some time in past...like....(current time - 30 minutes).

Comment: The value in the 'putOnQueueTime' property is a string, right? You can use a SimpleDateFormat in the expression to format any date in the format you want.

Comment: I was thinking of setting the time in milliseconds. I tried <jms:selector expression="putOnQueueTime+30000 &lt; #[function:now]"/> but it's not working. I get "WebSphere MQ classes for JMS has given JMS Provider a message selector with invalid syntax"

Comment: See the "Message Selectors" section in http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/index.html?javax/jms/Message.html

Comment: Sorry.....what am I looking for in the Message Selectors section? I read it twice.....but unable to pin point the issue. I see this ... "Date and time values should use the standard long millisecond value."....but that's what I'm trying to do. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Expressions don't see supported in selectors so I think you should pre-compute the cutoff timestamp, something like `<jms:selector expression="putOnQueueTime &gt; #[function:now-1800000]"/>`

Comment: What did the expression evaluate to? What was the selector string after evaluation?

Comment: The Mule Server wouldn't start due to syntax error. I tried          http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18597143/mule-quartz-endpoint-not-commiting-transaction, but that's another issue.

Comment: I may have it all mixed up! Is the JMS selector expression provided to underlying infrastructure (MQ)? Which means, it has to be a static expression and not a dynamic one like I'm trying?

Comment: No, Mule should evaluate the expression before passing it to the underlying JMS broker. If Mule fails to evaluate the expression, this is a bug.

Comment: Even if mule evaluates the expression, what I need is current time - 10 minutes (for example). If current time is 3:30 PM, selector is set for putOnQueueTime > 3:20 PM. Even at 4:00 PM, the selector is still set to putOnQueueTime > 3:20 PM as opposed to 3:50 PM. Am I thinking right?

Comment: The expression should be evaluated at each poll: if it's not the case, it's at best an improvement request for Mule, at worst a bug.

Comment: Hmmm...ok....in that case....I'm getting an error with the expression <jms:selector expression="putOnQueueTime &gt; #[function:now-1800000]"/>. The error is something like..."WebSphere MQ classes for JMS has given JMS Provider a message selector with invalid syntax". I'm confused with the statement "The expression should be evaluated at each poll". Where is poll involved? Again....Thanks for all the help!

Comment: I was trying to achieve what you were explaining here...https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-4119

Comment: LOL did so much stuff in Mule I totally forgot about this one :) Then try the same using either a quartz endpoint or a poll element.

Comment: I'm trying a quartz endpoint with <quartz:job-endpoint ref="retryQueue"/>. On the endpoint, I'm trying to set a selector. Few issues....1) Selector does not work. 2) A simple selector works..like "putOnQueueTime > 0", but it picks only 1 message at a time. 3) If subflow throws an exception, the message is rolled back, even though I'm catching the exception.

Comment: The exception strategy issue with Quartz seems to be https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-6989

Comment: Hmmm..... I have <quartz:inbound-endpoint......</quartz:inbound-endpoint> do something; do something; <choice-exception-strategy><catch-exception-strategy></catch-exception-strategy><rollback-exception-strategy><on-redelivery-attempts-exceeded></on-redelivery-attempts-exceeded></rollback-exception-strategy></choice-exception-strategy>. The flow goes through Rollback exception strategy, but doesn't enter the <on-redelivery-attempts-exceeded> even though the counter (JMSXDeliveryCount) shows the correct redelivery count.

Comment: I am marking this answer as useful but not "yet" accepted since the selector is not working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

We were trying to achieve this in one of the projects I'm working on, and tried what was being suggested in the other answer here, and it did not work, with various variantions. The problem is that the jms:selector doesn't support MEL, since it's relies on ActiveMQ classes.

We registered a support-ticket to Mulesoft, and their reply was that this is not supported.

What we ended up doing was this:

1. Create a simple Component, which does a `Thread.sleep(numberOfMillis)`, where the number of millis is defined in a property.
2. In the flow that was supposed to delay processing, we added this component as the first step after reading the message from the inbound endpoint.

Not the best solution ever made, but it works..