# Mule 3.3.1 until-successful losing messages due to busy threads

Tags: multithreading, mule, blocking

I have 2 flows. FlowA receives calls (htp-inbound) and places message on a queue. FlowB picks up messages from this queue and enters until-successful loop. Until successful makes an outbound call.

```
<flowA>
  <http-inbound/>
  <put message on queueA/>
</flowA>
<flowB>
  <jms:inbound queueA>
  <until-successful>
     <http-outbound/>
  </until-successful>
</flowB>
```

I am running this in Debug mode with a breakpoint where outbound call is made within untilsuccessful. I see that every call creates a new thread (until-successful) till we reach 15. The 16th call onwards, since thread pool is full, execution is continued in flowB's thread. I see 16 more flowB threads created. After that, when flowA puts a message on the queue, flowB picks it up, but I'm unable to figure out where it goes next :( The messsage is lost! It is not trying to make any outbound call.

I'm thinking 16 is the default thread pool size.

What is the expected behavior when until-successful is blocked? I expected the messages to queue up when all threads are busy.

Please let me know if I need to rephrase the question.

I am running in debug mode and may have messed up...so....please bear with me.

Answer (score 1):

You're right: 16 is the default thread pool size in Mule.

The message should not be lost: it should be accumulated in the `until-successful` object store, waiting to be picked up as soon as one of the thread becomes available again.

The core issue is that `until-successful` uses the default work manager which as a non-configurable threading profile. If it was possible to configure a custom threading profile, you would define a non-zero value for `maxBufferSize` which would then accumulate messages instead of triggering the pool exhausted action (of course, until the buffer is full, but that is another issue).

But for now, there is really no way out. `until-successful` is fixed with 16 threads the "if exhausted run" action.

This is a known issue: see point #1 here https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-7035 Please upvote this JIRA.

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention, I did set up persistent object store, but I don't see any more messages accumulating there. I see 31 messages.

Comment: Mmmh, OK, I need to try to reproduce this in order to give a more informed answer. Stay tuned.

Comment: Thanks a lot David. When until successful threads were all busy, I expected "FlowB" to just stick message in object store and continue (till object store is exhausted), I didn't expect another set of Flow threads to be spawned to complete the tasks. Will wait for your feeback.

Comment: Your expectations are correct. There's potentially a bug here.

Comment: Sorry to provide piece-meal information :( I did notice that DefaultContent instantiates a MuleWorkManager with `DEFAULT_THREADING_PROFILE` which is an `ImmutableThreadingProfile` with `DEFAULT_POOL_EXHAUST_ACTION` which is inturn equal to WHEN_EXHAUSTED_RUN, which causes `pool.setRejectedExecutionHandler(new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy());` CallerRunsPolicy comments....
/**A handler for rejected tasks that runs the rejected task
directly in the calling thread of the <tt>execute</tt> method, unless the executor has been shut down, in which case the task    is discarded.

Comment: But `until-successful` **schedules** the execution of its inner message processors so this scheduling should always happen, whether or not all the threads are busy.

Comment: I thought....Until successful eventually calls `executor.execute(work);` When all threads are busy, this throws some rejected exception and rejected execution handler is called which, in this case, runs the work in the caller's thread. This is the reason for multiple flowB threads is what I thought.

Comment: That is not normal, it shouldn't work like this. I will try to reproduce and open a bug ticket if I can confirm the issue.

Comment: Appreciate your assistance. Sorry for the long discussion.

Comment: Did you get a chance to look into it?

Comment: Oh sorry. Just saw your updated answer. I'm still not sure as to what is happening to the messages once all 15 + 16 threads are busy. The message is definitely not in the queue and it has not been processed either. Are they lost?

Comment: They shouldn't be, they should be in-memory in-transit in the blocked threads. Note that since you have a JMS inbound, you actually do not need to use `until-sucessful` but instead should rather use JMS transactions / redelivery to re-execute the HTTP outbound until it succeeds. `until-sucessful` is there for cases when it's not possible to rely on transactional transport to perform redeliveries.

Comment: I agree until-successful is not optimal soln. for my scenario, but am unable to set up a proper retry pattern :( Many hurdles like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18475090/jms-message-selector-in-mule-using-date. As far as the message is concerned, it is definitely picked up from the queue, but I don't see it anywhere! It is not even in the persistent storage. As I mentioned before, I can see a maximum of 31 files (messages) in persistent storage. I was in debug mode and it executes some `process(next)` and that's it :(

Comment: To be able to store the current message in the object store, Mule would need a thread but it can't get any thread anymore to process messages down the flow so the execution doesn't even reach the `until-successful`.

Comment: Right. I saw that. Only question.....what happens to the message? :( I was hoping it is thrown back on the queue but doesn't seem to be the case. I don't see any exceptions either. Sorry for the prolonged discussion.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40527/discussion-between-david-dossot-and-jeet)

Comment: Sure. Unfortunately, I can't access chat from my work :(. Will touch base in evening.

Comment: Awesome work :) I was saying: consume the JMS messages transactionally to have the guarantee you won't lose any.