# retry strategy in mule alternative for until-successful

Tags: http, mule

I am trying to implement retry strategy for a http outbound. After Googling, I found out that until-successful is having good capability to retry. But, maximum number of threads available for this API is 32. Hence, messages will be lost once the thread count reaches 32 and hence it might result in performance issues. Could someone clarify whether this issue is fixed in mule.
What are the other alternative strategies available ? Any suggestions/links/sample/pseudo code is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no limit to the number of retries you can attempt with `until-successful`.

I have no idea where you got this "32" from...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19728945/mule-3-3-1-until-successful-losing-messages-due-to-busy-threads  I came across this question. 32 I was referring was not about retry attempts. I was referring to parallel threads active.

Comment: Oh 16 threads, OK. Yes, this has been fixed in Cascade: https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/mule-3.5.0-cascade/core/src/main/java/org/mule/routing/UntilSuccessful.java#L63

Comment: Is this fix available in 3.4 ??