# JMS filter by timestamp using message selectors

Tags: java, jms, mule, dataweave

I am trying to only consume JMS messages that are at least 15 minutes old, but I don't have JMS 2.0, so I cannot use 'delivery delay' when I publish the messages.

I tried to try use a 'message selector' when I consume messages, to filter the messages by their timestamp - 15 minutes. But I can't get it to work.

It's not an option to upgrade to JMS 2.0 at this time because all integrations will have to be re-tested.

Related link:
 - [JMS Message Selector in Mule using date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18475090/jms-message-selector-in-mule-using-date)

My setup:

- Mule Runtime: 4.1.5 EE
- Dataweave: 2.0
- JMS: 1.1

Comment: You need to provide the details of what you tried (e.g. the Mule config, selector syntax, etc.), what you expected to happen, and what actually happened.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I will provide the details shortly.

Answer (score 0):

use a choice router and compare your message timestamp found in attributes.headers.timestamp >= now().minutes - 15 minutes

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to find a way so I don't have to fetch the message from JMS first, because then I will have to put it back again if the timestamp is not older than 15 minutes.